# Formal Proof of Minimum of maximum between two values

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the following minimization problem:

$\min_{X} \left[ \max \left( \left| X \right|, \left| X -T^2 \right| \right) \right]$

I know the answer is $X = 0.5 T^2$ but I am looking for a formal proof of that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $X>T^2/2$, then $$\vert X\vert=X>T^2/2.$$ On the other hand, if $X<T^2/2$, then $$\vert X-T^2\vert=T^2-X>T^2-T^2/2=T^2/2.$$ Hence, the minimum over all $X$ is at least $T^2/2$. Plugging in $X=T^2/2$ tells us that the minimum is at most $$\max(\vert T^2/2 \vert, \vert T^2/2-T^2\vert)=T^2/2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you solve such problems in general if you did not know the solution?

Comment: My first guess would be that the minimum should be found where $\vert X\vert =\vert X-T^2\vert$. The idea being that if one is bigger, then I could vary $X$ a bit and make the bigger term a bit smaller while the smaller term does not change too much as everything is continuous. However, then the value we started from wasn't the minimum.

Comment: If you reflect on my previous comment, then you see that you should check the individual local minima and the points where the two functions intersect.

Comment: Thanks, now I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via linear programming by introducing a variable $Z$ and linear constraints.  The problem is to minimize $Z$ subject to
\begin{align}
Z &\ge X \tag1\label1\\
Z &\ge -X \tag2\label2\\
Z &\ge X-T^2 \tag3\label3\\
Z &\ge -(X-T^2) \tag4\label4
\end{align}
As you noted, $X=Z=T^2/2$ is optimal.
The optimal dual variables $\pi=(1/2,0,0,1/2)$ provide a short certificate of optimality.  Explicitly, multiplying \eqref{1} through \eqref{4} by $\pi$ yields
$$(1/2)Z+0Z+0Z+(1/2)Z \ge (1/2)X+0(-X)+0(X-T^2)+(1/2)(-X+T^2),$$
which simplifies to
$$Z \ge T^2/2,$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter proof (without linear programming), motivated by plotting the graphs of $Y=|X|$ and $Y=|X-T^2|$:
$$\max(|X|,|X-T^2|) = |X-T^2/2| + T^2/2 \ge T^2/2$$